# How to retrieve error messages from Sabre API

Tags: sabre

I am using the getReservationRQ API (I am able to retrieve other info from the API) but I am not able to echo out the error messages. Does anyone have any ideas? Please see my code below.

```
private function handle_api_error($xml) {
    //echo "<textarea>".$xml->asXML()."</textarea>";
    $ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
    $soap = $xml->children($ns['soap-env'])->Body;      
    //$this->echo_xml($soap);
    foreach($soap->children($ns['stl17'])->GetReservationRS->Errors as $error) {
        $error_msg .= $error->Message.'<br />';
    }
    $this->error_msg="Sabre SOAP API error: ".$error_msg;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use some tool like Postman or SoapUI to see the actual error you are getting.
My guess is that it might be a different namespace: $ns['???']